# Can you play your numbers in Backgammon in a way to block one of them?

Tags: backgammon

First of all I apologize if my question is hard to understand, I'm not familiar with Backgammon glossary.

Let's say you rolled 3 and 6. In a certain situation the only way to play both 3 and 6 is to play them from one of your checkers from which you have to play 3 then 6 (6 is initially blocked). Now my question is are you allowed to play 3 from another checker into a position where you can't play 6 from any position anymore? And if there's a rule regarding this, can you please tell me what is it called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic rule of backgammon is that you must play in a way that maximises the use of your pips.

If you have a board that can use both 3 and 6, you must choose such move over any move that only uses 3 or only uses 6.

If you have a board that allows the use of 3 or 6 but not both, you must choose a move that uses only 6 over any move that uses only 3.